# How to rotate a div across the axis of an svg circle

Tags: css

I have a black circle and a small red circle on the axis of the bigger one:
[image]

Both are created with simple svg code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <svg className="main-svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle pathLength="25" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" />
      </svg>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle
          className="small-circle"
          transform-origin="center"
          fill="green"
          pathLength="25.5"
          cx="50%"
          cy="50%"
          r="50%"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's easy to rotate the smaller one, because both circles have the same radius so you just need to change the degree:

svg {
position: absolute;
}

```
.small-circle {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 25;
  stroke-dashoffset: -2.5;
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
}
```

However I would like to insert some content into that red circle svg, namely use a div, and to my knowledge it's very difficult to do with svg. How can I create a rotating div instead of the red svg, hopefully without constant pixel values to it's sizable like the svgs?

The code on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fwmjzn?file=style.css

Comment: If you use javascript you can synchronise the position of the div on the svg and just overlay it with z-index. Though maybe a better solution is not using an svg at all and instead using a div to replace the circle and put border on it with border-radius: 50%

Answer (score 1):

Although [<foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) can be inserted to SVG, It's hard to implement your requirement.

Because of  **.small-circle** is rendered by stroke, it's hard to locate x and y's positions when it is rotating.

Maybe using div and CSS3 is a good implement.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-iq2aqm?file=App.tsx,style.css,index.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <svg className="main-svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle pathLength="25" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" />
      </svg>
      <div className="small-circle">A</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
.small-circle {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: coral;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2.5vw;
  margin-left: -2.5vw;
  position: absolute;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  transform-origin: 52.5vw center;
  animation: rotate 8s linear infinite;

  text-align: center;
}
```

hope help you.